# Type problems with DOM elements in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom

What is the easiest way to deal with DOM type problems in TypeScript?

I've found two (ugly) solutions:
1. // @ts-ignore, which will make the compiler ignore the problem.
2. Use the "quick fix" tool, to add type info to the type library.
Do I have to download better type libraries, or is there something I have misunderstood?

For example, to have my code work cross browser, I sometimes need to access "non standard" properties. Here tsc complains about divObj.document:

```
let document:Document = divObj.ownerDocument || divObj.document;
```

The type library also seem to have wrong info for some common DOM properties. Here it thinks that document.body is of type HTMLElement instead of HTMLBodyElement. (And even if I cast to the right type, it still doesn't know that createTextRange is a function on that class - CORRECTION: it is a IE specific function, so the behavior here is correct).

```
let bodyObj = document.body;
let range = bodyObj.createTextRange()
```

Comment: What are the type errors you are seeing? Can you provide the full code? I don't see `createTextRange()` defined in any documentation when searching Google or in the Chrome console: `document.body.createTextRange // returns undefined`. Is this a valid method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the creators of the dom.typings had a good reason to type `document.body` as a general `HTMLDocument`. This `createTextRange` method is defined on the `HTMLInputElement`.  Why do you expect it on the document body?

Comment: Thanks @skovy and Andreas_D. Sorry, my bad about createTextRange. It is a IE specific function, so you are correct. However, HTMLBodyElement does have some properties that don't exist on HTMLElement, so that is still a problem.